# Convert Array's into Individual Values in .forEach()

Tags: javascript, arrays

working on a data transformation project that is taking queries from five different databases, and merge them together. (There are two record sets that are very similar to each other and another set of two that are similar to each other.)

Three of five returned records are fine. The other two (which are similar) are oddly returning certain fields as arrays instead of just single values.

i.e.:

```
dbRecords = [
   {
        FirstName: ['john', 'john doe']
    }
]
```

it's definitely due to poor data maintenance, but I want to convert these to single values and I was thinking I could do it something like this.

```
dbRecords.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(i => {
        if(i instanceof Array){
            item = item[0];
        }
    }
});
```

Would that do the trick?

Comment: Why not test it and find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Three of five returned records are fine. The other two (which are similar) are oddly returning certain fields as arrays instead of just single values."*

From that statement, it sounds like you know precisely which two fields are the unexpected arrays. In that case, you shouldn't use a loop, but rather target those fields directly.

So assuming the fields are `FirstName` and `LastName`, you can do it like this:

```
dbRecords = dbRecords.map(({FirstName:[FirstName], LastName:[LastName], ...rest}) => 
  ({FirstName, LastName, ...rest})
);
```

This takes advantage of parameter destructuring and "rest sytnax" in object literals to extract the first array member two fields that interest you, as well as the rest of the fields into a separate object, then returns a new object with the extracted values along with the rest of the fields.

Here's a working example:

```js
let dbRecords = [{
   FirstName: ['john', 'john doe'],
   LastName: ['doe', 'john doe'],
   OtherField: "foobar"
}, {
   FirstName: ['bob', 'bob smith'],
   LastName: ['smith', 'bob smith'],
   OtherField: "raboof"
}];

dbRecords = dbRecords.map(({FirstName:[FirstName], LastName:[LastName], ...rest}) => 
  ({FirstName, LastName, ...rest})
);

console.log(dbRecords);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would that do the trick?

No, cause `item` is the object and not the value you want to change, you would have to do:

```
 item[i] = item[i][0];
```

And additionally, `i` is always a `string` and never an `Array` the check must be:

```
 if(item[i] instanceof Array){
```

And then you would have to store it back to the db.

PS: `i` is a bad variable name, why dont you just take `key` or something similar?

Comment: It was just for the sake of the example, but yes it's a horribly vague variable name

Comment: Also not storing into db afterward

Comment: @chris yes. Examples are there to vaguely explain to others what you want to do, using confusing identifiers somehow defeats that purpose ..

Comment: I'll do better next time. Make it a habit to give meaningful names.